# Animated SVG clipping path not working in Firefox

Tags: svg, transform, clipping

I have a svg with clipping mask, animated with Greensock GSAP. (JS animates the CSS3 transform property)

Works fine in Chrome, Safari, IE, ... but not in Firefox.

**HTML**

```
<svg version="1.1" width="240" height="240" >
  <defs>
    <clipPath id="MASK_1">
        <rect class="mask" x="60" y="60" width="100" height="100" />
    </clipPath>
  </defs>
  <rect clip-path="url(#MASK_1)" x="0" y="0" width="240" height="240" />
</svg>

<br /><a href="#" class="btn-1">mask animation in</a>
<br /><a href="#" class="btn-2">mask animation out</a>
```

**JavaScript**

```
$('.btn-1').bind('click', function() {
  TweenMax.to('.mask',  3, {scaleX: 0.5});
});
$('.btn-2').bind('click', function() {
  TweenMax.to('.mask',  3, {scaleX: 1});
});
```

**Test** (Test in Chrome AND Firefox)

http://jsfiddle.net/drb2szbw/1/

Any ideas?

Comment: Firefox does not support transforms as styles very well as that's part of SVG 2 which is not complete as a specification. Chrome and IE do support that part of the SVG 2 specification. So best not use jquery to modify SVG given that it's not doing something that's SVG 1.1 compliant.

Comment: Animating the attributes directly worked:
http://jsfiddle.net/drb2szbw/2/

Comment: As a reference for anyone searching I wanted to add a link for GSAP's plugin: http://greensock.com/docs/#/HTML5/GSAP/Plugins/AttrPlugin/
wow! i know the comments are not the place to say it, but thanks for this @WouterDierick